# Android : Rating bar not occupying complete space available

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application in which I have a `RatingBar`. Currently for testing, I am setting its value randomly between 1-5. For some reason, the rating bar is always starting from center, and is never occupying the complete space available. Here is how it looks in the app :
[image]

The entire space left of rating bar is what I have given in XML, but it's not getting filled.

One other problem with Rating bar is, how can I add a text to left of the RatingBar. Something like `Text...(XXXXX)`. Thank you

Code :

```
   <RatingBar
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/productStars"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:scaleX="0.3"
                android:scaleY="0.3"
                android:stepSize="1"
                android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/description"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/description" />
```

*Update*

Entire layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:background="@color/common_action_bar_splitter"

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/productImage"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_image"

                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comments"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/productStars"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/description"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/description" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productImage"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/productImage"
                android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
                android:typeface="monospace"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_above="@+id/comments"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/productImage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/productName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/productImage"
                android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3dp" />

            <RatingBar
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:id="@+id/productStars"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:scaleX="0.3"
                android:scaleY="0.3"
                android:stepSize="1"
                android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/description"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/description" />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/swapButton"
                android:src="@drawable/swappossible"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/productStars"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/productStars" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try giving wrap_content to the width ?

Comment: Show full layout please

Comment: @user1841702 : Yes, then the bar width increases overlapping the button and image on left.

Comment: @Divers : Main post edited, kindly check it out.

Comment: Can the two downvoters explain why this was downvoted, as wrap_content is not solving the problem, quick to judge hard to learn I guess. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your rating bar with this

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/productStars"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:numStars="5"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/description"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/description" />
```

Comment: @We are Borg You should try this

Answer (score 1):

**Don't give fix width** to rating bar, keep it `wrap_content`. To make rating bar smaller use this instead

```
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
```

Add this to your rating bar
According to your code it should be like this

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/productStars"
    android:numStars="5"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/description"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/description"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Make height wrap_content too and remove `scaleX` and `scaleY` too

Comment: This makes the stars disappear